# Publisher in Pub/Sub should be Synchronous or Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dom-events, anti-patterns

My view on mechanism:

- Pattern wise publisher should just publish an event and should not care about listeners / subscribers for that topic / event.
- In case of JavaScript, lot of frameworks for Pub / Sub publishes event in Sync manner
- for example : framework just maintains map of event to function.
- on particular event occurrence, it iterates over subscribers and calls function one by one - > function_1.apply(context, args) and then function_2.apply(context, args)
- This makes it Synchronous as, unless and until function_1 finishes, function_2 is unaware that particular event happened.

What is an ideal way of implementing Pub / Sub in JavaScript ?

Comment: You just said "framework" without saying which framework. A publisher is asynchronous. Subscriber is also asynchronous, but since JS is single-threaded you can't make the **execution** of subscriber async. If you have a subscriber that blocks, the whole thing blocks until it's done and yes, the next function in callback map will do nothing until previous one finishes.

Comment: @Mjh Though, we can't make the execution of subscriber async, can't we just give responsibility of executing functions to JavaScript runtime, rather than invoking functions one after the other via call / apply ?

Comment: So if I got this right, your question is can you execute functions but not in order of their definition in the callback map? Whatever you do, the functions will be executed one after another. Now the problem is, are those functions blocking or non-blocking as well?

Comment: Exactly, and you never know subscribed functions are blocking or non-blocking

Comment: In that case, the answer provided by BJ Safdie is what you're looking for. Also, you can take a look at [PubSubJS github repo](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS), specifically at [this](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS/blob/master/src/pubsub.js#L121) line of code where you see that the answer provided here and the library linked do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add an "enqueue" parameter to my publish method that when truthy, wraps the actual publish in a setTimeout(..., 0) so that the publisher can choose to have the handling fire immediately, or have it enqueued in the JavaScript execution queue, allowing the current path of execution to complete first.

If you are maintaining your own list of subscribers, you can have the subscribe method implement the enqueue flag as an attribute of the subscription.  Thus the publisher could enqueue individual subscribers based on their preference as indicated in their subscription.

Comment: Another thing subscribers can ask for is Priority ?